# How to disable Greasemonkey's smart coding?

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

I have very hard time coding in Greasemonkey editor on Firefox, because it is constantly trying to be smarter than me and thus adding things that I never intend to add on the first place.

How can I disable those extra "smart" features?

Comment: Which Greasmonkey editor are you talking about? Because the script editor is selected via the Greasmonkey options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That editor is not Greasemonkey's; it's [the Firefox Scratchpad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Scratchpad) and it's actually pretty kick-ass.

But if you don't like it, you can set Greasemonkey to use your favorite text editor via the options:

(Click an image for a larger view)

> [image: Opening GM options]
>
> [image: GM options dialog]

You can set the text editor to just about anything, but it's best if the editor has real UTF-8 support.  ([Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) works well.)

Comment: Ah, thank god! Much better. Scratchpad is cool, but it lacks too many options. I prefer to not make a computer to do my job for me too much. (autocompletion some strings is okay, anything else usually is waste of my time because it never guesses my intentions right). ->upvoted + accepted.